# How do I list my items in Dropbox by access level?

Tags: privacy, dropbox, sharing, access-control

I found myself accidentally sharing sensitive information in Dropbox. This has happened multiple times. So I want to check what I'm sharing and with whom. I'd like to see a list of my items (files and folders) in Dropbox, sorted by access level: first public, then people with the link, then shared with specific people, and finally private. Is that possible?

Or is there any other way of achieving this goal?

This question applies to [Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90615/how-do-i-list-my-items-in-google-drive-by-access-level) as well, for which I've posted a separate question as suggested.